# Get var from another function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello im trying to get a variable from another function

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var totalFiles;

$(".filesUpload").on("change", function() { 
                    var files = $(".filesUpload").prop("files");
                    var names = $.map(files, function(val) { return val.name; });
                    $("#uploadBar").modal('show');
                    var totalFiles = names.length;
                });
                $("#uploadBar").on("shown.bs.modal", function() { var test = totalFiles; alert(test); });
```

But right now i only get undefined on the totalFiles, but if i have a alert right after var totalFiles = names.length i get the right result, anyone knows what i can do and what am i doing wrong?

PS. I've checked other threads aswell and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your references to `totalFiles`. You have one declared globally and then declared it locally in `$(".filesUpload").on("change", function() {`.

This is what it needs to be :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var totalFiles;

$(".filesUpload").on("change", function() { 
                    var files = $(".filesUpload").prop("files");
                    var names = $.map(files, function(val) { return val.name; });
                    $("#uploadBar").modal('show');
                     totalFiles = names.length;
                });
                $("#uploadBar").on("shown.bs.modal", function() { var test = totalFiles; alert(test); });
```

Just remove `'var'` from the 1st function.

Comment: God that was embarrassing. I stop with the coding for now. I get back to it tomorrow, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Do not declare the variable twice. In your `onChange` function, just use `totalFiles` rather than declaring it again with the `var` keyword.

```
$(".filesUpload").on("change", function() {
    ...
    totalFiles = names.length;
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring a local variable inside your callback. `totalFiles = names.length;` is the right way to update the global variable.

```
var totalFiles;
$(".filesUpload").on("change", function() { 
    var files = $(".filesUpload").prop("files");
    var names = $.map(files, function(val) { return val.name; });
    $("#uploadBar").modal('show');
    totalFiles = names.length;
});
```